# Can I safely connect my A6 GPRS module to this 5V 2A phone adapter

Tags: gsm, voltage-level

I have an A6 GPRS module, and my Samsung phone power adapter has output of 5V and 2A. But it also says 9V and 1.6A

[image: My Samsung Mobile Power Adapter]
My Phone's Adapter

So would it damage my A6 GPRS Module if I plug this to it via the micro usb power port? (especially because it also says 9V)?

[image: My A6 GPRS module]

My A6 GPRS module

Comment: Although you have marked your question "Arduino-Uno" and "Arduino-Mega", it's not about Arduino.

Comment: @StarCat corrected.

Comment: That is an adapter that support USB Power Delivery (specifically USB PD rev. 2.0/3.0). So it will put out 5V, unless it's specifically asked to deliver 9V by the device that's plugged in. You device will never request this, so it will always get 5V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard output for USB is 5V but there are some such chargers that will output more for enhanced charging output on devices that support it.

In this case the adapter will default to 5V and will only upgrade to 9V if the device requests it.  The GPRS module will not request 9V and so the adapter will continue to provide only 5V which is what you want.